# Notification.bigContentView is deprecated in API 24 (Nougat) what is the alternative?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I just upgraded compile sdk version to API 24 from API 23 and it seems the `Notification.bigContentView` is deprecated.

So the question what is the equivalent method in API 24 to set bigContentView in Android API 24(Nougat)?

Comment: For all the news about `Notification` you can refer to the official  android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html), hope that helps you

Comment: @AbAppletic pls update the link to what i have added in my answer it exactly points to where you should see

Comment: I understand that you are aware of that link, however it will be useful for future users :)

Comment: @AbAppletic ok if it will be helpful then its fine

Comment: @AbAppletic is your issue solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148858/android-calligraphy-library-default-font-overrides-set-font

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `NotificationBuilderCompat` has a new method `setCustomBigContentView()`
in the v4 support library 24.

You can use this method to avoid the deprecated warning and the method is backward compatible.

Quoting the Docs:

As of N, this field may be null. The expanded notification view is determined by the inputs to `Notification.Builder`; a custom RemoteViews can optionally be supplied with `setCustomBigContentView(RemoteViews)`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#bigContentView

Comment: Thanks, This helped!